# Docker при монтировании перетирает каталог с библиотеками vendor

Tags: php, docker, mount

Есть проблема с тем, что docker перетирает не существующий каталог в контейнере вместо того чтобы примонтировать его на хост

В базовом образе я скачиваю composer и устанавливаю PHP-библиотеки, с этим всё в порядке. Но как только пытаюсь выполнить монтирование "./:/var/www", то в контейнере сразу стирается каталог с библиотеками "vendor", потому что его изначально нет на хосте.

Можно ли настроить монтирование таким образом, что если на хосте нет каталога или файла, то он бы создавался из контейнера?

Конфиг docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"
services:
    php:
        image: php:latest #local image PHP
        container_name: php
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
        networks:
            - internal
        restart: "unless-stopped"
networks:
    internal:
        driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 0):

нет нельзя.

конфиг как раз для того, что бы указывать что должно монтироваться, а что нет.

Поэтому монтируйте проект в контейнер, и выполняйте в нём команды composer install и т.п именно внутри контейнера.
Отдельно в образе вы можете ставить дополнения для самого PHP  (gd, pdo_mysql и т.п.)